# DNS REquest Timed out

Tags: dns, active-directory

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory with DNS. I set my AD server DNS to 127.0.0.1

I am able to ping multiple websites. However, I am unable to join a computer to this domain and getting error "The Network Path was not found", yet the computer can ping the domain just fine and DNS is pointing to AD server in network settings

When I go to the AD server and run the following, I noticed I get:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup mydomain.sys
Server:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Name:    mydomain.sys
Address:  10.70.160.247
```

How do I fix this? Why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the localhost ip address which is only accessible to your processes running on your server itself; you should change your ip address to one that is accessible to other devices.
For example, if 10.70.160.247 is the ip-address of your domain server, then run the DNS service to listen on ip-address 10.70.160.247; not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Not sure I understand. This server is my AD server and DNS server which is why my IP is the lookup ip.